# How to dismiss file / save dialog originating from OS in HP Loadrunner Truclient

Tags: loadrunner, truclient

I have the exact same requirement as [this question](http://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/In-TruClient-for-IE9-how-to-close-File-Save-Open-Cancel-modal/td-p/6449036), except this is for Loadrunner 12 in Firefox.

Using TruClient all script action works till it open window's ( OS ) modal dialog  and stuck at handling this modal dialog. Are there any solutions or workarounds to handle this ?

I want to do two things.

1. Measure time till it open modal dialog
2. Cancel the dialog and move on to next steps

Answer (score 0):

1. This is an OS step with zero server interaction and is completely dependent upon the performance of the underlying operating system.  You should address this in functional testing with QTP and the timing capability built in there.  You appear to be commingling functional testing wither performance in the asking of this question. And, if the call up of the common dialog is slow how will you post your defect to Microsoft for them to fix it on your timeframe?
2. Have you considered using a standard web virtual user which runs at the presentation layer of the OSI model and which does not have the GUI dependencies of the Application layer?

Comment: The script presses a button which asks our service to export a given query to a CSV file. Generating the csv file obviously takes time to complete. I'd like to quantify the resource impact of this operation for large (100k) items. Is there a way to cancel a modal dialog, or move past it?

Comment: When you type in a filename and hit submit, it is at this point when the forum request, containing the filename which may be parameterized if need be (but often doesn't have to be).  You can time that request and the resulting response just find in a standard web virtual user.  Often the query results in a screen which says "processing..." and a status bar, when what is really happening behind the scenes is a request with an update coming back.  When the request is satisfied then the request loop exits. This is common when performance testing reporting systems